# Pass variable from JavaFx to JavaScript & Write code to trigger the button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, javafx

I tried to write a program to communicate between JavaFx and JavaScript/JQuery. I want my program to work like following,

A character(e.g. 'a') is passed to JavaFx by user input, then this character 'a' is passed to JavaScript. In JavaScript/JQuery, there five buttons, whose labels have one different characters. For example, button A has label 'a'; button B has label 'b', etc. Then JavaScript/JQuery finds that 'a' are matched, then button A is clicked.

I am stuck on 
1. how do I pass variable from **JavaFx** to **JavaScript**. I know how to pass variable from JavaScript to JavaFx.

2  how do make the button triggered when there is a match.  Normally, user clicked the button to trigger the action. In the code, there will be something like click(this).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Since I am working on a big project, I just made up the question above so it can mimic the part that I stuck on my project.  So I do not have code for this.  I think I just need to be pointed to a right direction.

Comment: So write a new program specifically for the purpose of demonstrating the issue, and post that. Descriptions of what you are trying to do without an example are too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use trigger Event [Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#input').on('keyup',function(){
var textInput = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
  if(textInput=="a"){
    $('#a').trigger('click');
    }
  if(textInput=="b"){
     $('#b').trigger('click');
    }
  if(textInput=="c"){
     $('#c').trigger('click');
    }
  if(textInput=="d"){
     $('#d').trigger('click');
    }
  if(textInput=="e"){
     $('#e').trigger('click');
    }
 
})
  $('#a').on('click',function(){
  alert("a");
  });
    $('#b').on('click',function(){
  alert("b");
  })
      $('#c').on('click',function(){
  alert("c");
  })
        $('#d').on('click',function(){
  alert("d");
  })
          $('#e').on('click',function(){
  alert("e");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input"><br><br>
<button id="a">A</button><button id="b">B</button><button id="c">C</button><button id="d">D</button><button id="e">E</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to click a button by code then just do this:

```
$("#myButtonId").click();
```

This code will click your button with id `myButtonId`